# Using deep learning or random forest

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, random-forest

I am very new to machine learning, and I am trying to build a model to classify [this data set (UCI heart disease)](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/heart+Disease). I have built a simple model using random forest and got an 80% accuracy. The size of the set is about 900. To get the best value possible, should I continue with random forest or go with deep learning (such as TensorFlow)?

Thanks!

Comment: good attempt...but u have to know one thing...deep learning needs to be apply only data is very huge..for less data u can go with random forest or xgboost...even u can tune the random forest model with mtry,ntree,kfold so that u can improve some more accuracy

Answer (score 2):

The given dataset has 303 observations and 76 features. This is usually considered very small. Deep learning needs plenty of data to be stable since it is highly nonlinear. Random forest is one option but simpler structured models can be considered. One important thing which have to be investigated in those situations is regularization. Fighting with over fitting looks like the main goal.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would optimise the Random Forest.

But of course you can also try a Deep Learning approach. You have to be very careful in choosing the number of layers and the number of neurons per layer as you may easily overfit the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can settle with Random forest for now since the dataset you are using is very low;
If you go for complex model you will easily be over-fitting it.

In parallel you can either try to get more data or resample the existing data (meanwhile).